# Java Servlet:Access property of object stored in session in another servlet

Tags: java

I created login page with user's credentials. After successful login I need to create an object of the user and store it in session. It works fine, but I cannot access values stored in this object in another servlet. I can only access the whole object itself, but I need separated values. Any idea? Please, help!

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
String firstName = rs.getString("firstname");
String lastName = rs.getString("lastname");
String email= rs.getString("email");
User userObj=new User(firstName,lastName,email);
```

this is how I access the object  in another servlet but I need only one value, firstName for now:

```
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    Object u = session.getAttribute("userObject");
    // here I need to access firstname;
```

Comment: `String firstName = ((User) u).getFirstName();` should do. You need to cast the object.

Comment: @ernest_k Make this an Answer so the Question can be closed.